"it is able to penetrate the human form undetected" implies that "it can pass through a person’s body without causing harm"
In a sample practice for Reading Comprehension, the first paragraph is

"Time travel took a small step away from science fiction and toward science recently when physicists discovered that sub-atomic particles known as neutrinos – progeny of the sun’s radioactive debris – can exceed the speed of light. The unassuming particle – it is electrically neutral, small but with a “non-zero mass” and able to penetrate the human form undetected – is on its way to becoming a rock star of the scientific world."

And a question asks whether the statement below can be confirmed as "True", "False", or "Not Given by the Passage".
The statement at hand is:
Neutrinos can pass through a person’s body without causing harm.
I answered "Not Given by the Passage" because there is no way we can conclude it. The neutrinos may be undetected but still can cause harm.
However, the official answer key maintains that "True" is the correct answer. I don't understand why. And there is no other indication related to the adversity or harmlessness of it in all of the following paragraphs.
....
After thinking for a while, now I suspect that the word "unassuming" suggests that it is harmless to human? perhaps because if it is "not showy", "not superior", "not attention-seeking", then it would not be classified as dangerous.

@user405662 you mean because it's "progeny of sun's radioactive debris" meaning its everywhere?

I agree with you, @Redsbefall, that the paragraph does not argue harmlessness. And the last word has not been said on the issue.

Gamma radiation can also pass through the human body undetected, but it can cause harm.

@Redsbefall As others have pointed out, there isn't enough information for us to know if the neutrinos cause harm or not. My earlier comment was a mistake on my part. I'm not sure I understand your above comment.

Also neutrinos were later shown to not be faster than light, which casts further doubt on the whole thing. Maybe in a universe where they exceed the speed of light, they're proven harmless?

People might infer, maybe. I'd agree with "not given by the passage", but for different (and possibly more pedantic) reasons. The passage says "penetrate" ie. go into. It says nothing about coming out the other side.

I tutor SATs and such. You are 100% right to never assume in these passages, as answers that include a small assumption are trick answers. You are right here, they are wrong: A knife stab is harmful, though the knife is later undetected.

The given answer apparently assumes that harm can be detected. So if it caused harm, we would detect that, and the penetration wouldn't be undetected.
